# .json extension file + timestamp + Pandas + Python

Tags: python, json, datetime, pandas, python-datetime

I have a .json file extension (logs.json) that was sent to me with the following data in it (I am showing only some of it as there are over 2,000 entries):

["2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:06:23+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:06:52+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:11:23+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:12:47+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:12:54+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:16:14+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:17:31+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:21:23+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:21:26+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:22:25+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:28:24+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:31:21+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:32:20+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:33:32+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:35:21+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:38:14+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:39:24+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:43:12+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:46:13+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:46:31+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:48:03+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:49:34+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:49:54+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:55:19+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:56:27+00:00", "2012-03-01T00:56:32+00:00"]

Using Pandas, I did:

```
import pandas as pd
logs = pd.read_json('logs.json')
logs.head()
```

And I get the following:

```
                           0
0  2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00
1  2012-03-01T00:06:23+00:00
2  2012-03-01T00:06:52+00:00
3  2012-03-01T00:11:23+00:00
4  2012-03-01T00:12:47+00:00

[5 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then, in order to assign the proper data type including the UTC zone, I do:

```
logs = pd.to_datetime(logs[0], utc=True)
logs.head()
```

And get:

```
0   2012-03-01 00:05:55
1   2012-03-01 00:06:23
2   2012-03-01 00:06:52
3   2012-03-01 00:11:23
4   2012-03-01 00:12:47
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is the above code correct to get my data in the right format?
2. where did my UTC zone go? and what if I want to create a column with the corresponding PST time and add it to this dataset in a data frame format?
3. I seem to recall that in order to obtain counts per day/week, or year, I need to add .day, .week, or .year somewhere (logs.day?), but I cannot figure it out and I am guessing that it is because of the current shape of my data. How do I get counts by day? week? year? so that I can plot the data? and how would I go with plotting the data?

Such simple questions that seem so hard for someone who is transitioning from R to using Python for Data Analysis! I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What format is the correct format, can you clearly indicate what is your desired format? An example would be great.

Comment: In future try to limit the amount of questions you ask (hopefully to one) in a single question unless they are literally just clarifications or so small it would be easy to answer. The more complex the question and multi faceted the more likely you are to get no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there may be a bug in the tz handling here, it's certainly possible that this should be converted by default (I was surprised that it wasn't, I suspect it's because it's just a list).

```
In [21]: s = pd.read_json(js, convert_dates=[0], typ='Series')  # more honestly this is a Series

In [22]: s.head()
Out[22]:
0   2012-03-01 00:05:55
1   2012-03-01 00:06:23
2   2012-03-01 00:06:52
3   2012-03-01 00:11:23
4   2012-03-01 00:12:47
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To get counts of year, month, etc. I would probably use a DatetimeIndex (at the moment date-like columns don't have year/month etc methods, though I think they (c|sh)ould):

```
In [23]: dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(s)

In [24]: s.groupby(dti.year).size()
Out[24]:
2012    27
dtype: int64

In [25]: s.groupby(dti.month).size()
Out[25]:
3    27
dtype: int64
```

Perhaps it makes more sense to view the data as a TimeSeries:

```
In [31]: ts = pd.Series(1, dti)

In [32]: ts.head()
Out[32]:
2012-03-01 00:05:55    1
2012-03-01 00:06:23    1
2012-03-01 00:06:52    1
2012-03-01 00:11:23    1
2012-03-01 00:12:47    1
dtype: int64
```

This way you can use resample:

```
In [33]: ts.resample('M', how='sum')
Out[33]:
2012-03-31    27
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Kevin yes, you can groupby `dti.to_period('M')`. Tbh, most of the time you want datetime to be the index that way you can resample/groupby using TimeGrouper('M'). Edit: The above is for *month* to do hour use 'H'.

Comment: @Kevin it may be better to ask a new question (site helps that way), feel free to drop the url here if you do! Saying that, you can do `s.groupby([dti.day, dti.hour]).size()` if that's what you're after ?

Comment: @AndyHayden, thanks for your explanation. I've posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186651/. Appreciate!!